# A/B Test Checkout Magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, checkout, router

our projectmanager wants to A/B test different payment methods. He wants to be able to test that with an external analysing tool e.g. Google Website Optimizer, Econda. Because you need two diffenrent URLs for that test I think we need two complete independent checkouts.

Is it possible to override an existing checkout with a new frontname and two other payment methods? Do I have to clone the complete core checkout model?

Thanks a lot.

cradossk

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Google WSO to hide one of the payment methods on the onepage checkout itself. That would be much cleaner than trying to clone the entire checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Google Website Optimizer will help you at all. We're using few of javascript code and  magic to show correct experiment.